# Check SQL Database offline

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to check the integrity of MSSQL database when microsoft SQLServer itself not running (or) is not installed . Means i have mdf and ldf files of one database how can i check integrity( like  DBCC CHECKDB when database is online on sqlserver).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Almost by definition the only thing that can check a SQL Server database is... SQL Server.

So you will definitely need to have an instance available that you can use to check the files. Something like the (free) SQL Server Express should do the job if your database files are not too large, as you won't be running with lots of users.

Comment: I want to validate the dbs  when sqlserver itself offline means without using sqlserver. Is there any tools to do this work.